# Как остановить функцию через 5 секунд?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_data():
  

def countdown():
  time.sleep(5)
  print('bed')
  continue


def main():
    check = Timer(30.0, countdown)
    pars = Thread(target=get_data)
    check.start()
    pars.start()
    check.cansle()

for accaunt in bd:
   name = accaunt.split(':')[0]
   pas = accaunt.split(':')[1]
   user = wa(name)
   main()
```

Каким образом это можно воплотить, задача: `get_data` может зависнуть, но если сработает, то успеет исполниться быстрее 5 секунд. По моей логике `countdown` запускается раньше `get_data` и спит 5 секунд. Если `get_data` сработала, `countdown` отменится, а если зависнет, `countdown` должна вызвать `continue` для цикла и вынудить его перейти к проверке следующего элемента. На сколько это реально, и как вызвать этот `continue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def get_data(x, n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(f"{x}: Get Data {i} of {n}")
        time.sleep(1)
  
def main(x, n):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_data, args=(x,n))
    p.start()
    p.join(5) # ждём не более 5 секунд
    if p.is_alive():  # если поток всё ещё выполняется
        print(f"[{x}: {n}]  Timeout!!! Kill 'em all :-E")
        p.terminate()
        p.join()

for account,n in [("my", 10), ("your", 3), ("their", 1)]:
   main(account, n)
```

```
my: Get Data 1 of 10
my: Get Data 2 of 10
my: Get Data 3 of 10
my: Get Data 4 of 10
my: Get Data 5 of 10
[my: 10]  Timeout!!! Kill 'em all :-E
your: Get Data 1 of 3
your: Get Data 2 of 3
your: Get Data 3 of 3
their: Get Data 1 of 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[@GrAnd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1353851) спасибо, твой вариант вполне приемлемо работает у меня.

А это то что успел найти я:

```
from  wrapt_timeout_decorator  import
def get_data():

@timeout(5)
def main():
    get_data()

for accaunt in bd:
   name = accaunt.split(':')[0]
   pas = accaunt.split(':')[1]
   user = wa(name)
   main()
```