# Как остановить потоки по времени, что бы программа закрылась

Tags: python

Имеется такой код:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time

count_thread = 4

def download(param): 
    global start
    global end    
    if now > start and now < end:
        # остановить все потоки, что бы программа закрылась
    pass

pool = ThreadPool(count_thread)

start =  dt(2021,12,8, 19,00)
end = dt(2021,12,8, 20,00)

results = pool.map(download_, param)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Программа выполняет функцию, как сделать, что бы она закрывалась остановив перед этим потоки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903791/how-to-terminate-a-multiprocess-in-python-when-a-given-condition-is-met

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1353827/Как-остановить-функцию-через-5-секунд

Comment: непонятно как потоки пула остановить

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429243/multiprocessing-pool-how-to-cancel-all-running-processes-if-one-returns-the-de

Comment: Вот это дельно! Благодарю!!!

Answer (score 0):

Можно с `return`:

```py
if now > start and now < end:
    return False
```

Comment: поток не остановится, просто будут браться следующие данные пока массив данных в param не закончится

Comment: либо с попробуй с функцией `exit` или `quit`

Comment: если имеете ввиду программу закрыть, то когда первый поток дойдет до этой команды программа закроется и информация в других потоках потеряется